# FDT and ATAGS support not compiled in - hanging ### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###

Tags: linux, u-boot, device-tree

I'm following the tutorial from the below mentioned website to install Linux on SoCkit by Terasic:

https://zhehaomao.com/blog/fpga/2013/12/24/sockit-2.html.

This is my first time building a Linux, so I am still learning. I was able to complete all the steps shown in the tutorial, but when I try to boot, it gives me error saying

```
Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree Could not find a valid device tree
```

Now, I know the `.dtb` file is on the SD card and I can load it using the `fatload` command of u-boot. After I load the `.dtb` file and run `bootm` command I get the error saying

```
FDT and ATAGS support not compiled in - hanging ### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###
```

I don't know where/how to enable this support. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this particular SD card I am using wasn't getting formatted (partitions file system) properly on a virtual machine. I was running Ubuntu 14 on VirtualBox. I then formatted on a laptop running ubuntu and re-wrote the SD card. It booted up just fine!